# open a new activity from a list view

Tags: android, listview

i'm making an app for listing clients , and when i click on his name from the listview i want to open a new acitivy with the details from that client.. but when i click on it doesn't open anything, the app still on the list view

here is my code:

```
package com.example.hp13_b200.testedesign;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;


public class listar_clientes extends ListActivity {
    private ListView list;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

    // url to get all products list
    private static String url_all_products = "http://192.168.137.100:81/androidapp/listar_clientes.php";

    // JSON Node names

    private static final String TAG_CLIENTE= "clientes";
    private static final String TAG_NOME = "nome";
    private static final String TAG_ABV = "nome2";




    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray products = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_listar_clientes);

        //list = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        // Hashmap for ListView
        productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Loading products in Background Thread
        new LoadAllProducts().execute();
        //  Log.v("COUNT-->",productsList.get(0).toString());
        // Get listview
        ListView list = getListView();
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem

                String nome = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText()
                        .toString();
                String abv = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.abv)).getText()
                        .toString();
                Log.d("Cod_conta: ", ""+nome);
                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        detalhes_cliente.class);
                // sending pid to next activity

                in.putExtra(TAG_NOME, nome);
                in.putExtra(TAG_ABV, abv);

                Log.d("entrou: ", "vai entrar" );

                // starting new activity and expecting some response back
                startActivity(in);
            }


        });
        // launching Edit Product Screen
//        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
//
//
//                // Starting new intent
//                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
//                        list_item.class);
//                // sending pid to next activity
//                in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);
//
//                // starting new activity and expecting some response back
//                startActivityForResult(in, 100);
//            }
//        });

      /*  ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                encomendas_user.this, productsList,
                R.layout.activity_list_item, new String[] { TAG_IDUSER,
                TAG_TITULO},
                new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name });
        // updating listview
        setListAdapter(adapter);*/
        // on seleting single product
        // launching Edit Product Screen

    }

    // Response from Edit Product Activity
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // if result code 100
        if (resultCode == 100) {
            // if result code 100 is received
            // means user edited/deleted product
            // reload this screen again
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }



    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(listar_clientes.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("A Carregar dados. Por favor Aguarde...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                //  int success = json.getInt(TAG_IDUSER);
                //Log.d("NAMSUCCESSE: ", ""+success);
                //if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products
                products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CLIENTE);

                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);


                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NOME);
                    String abv = c.getString(TAG_ABV);


                    Log.d("NAME TESTE: ", name);
                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_NOME, "Nome:"+" "+ name);
                    map.put(TAG_ABV,  "Abreviatura:"+" "+abv);



                   // if(UserInfo.userID==(Integer.parseInt(name))){
                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    productsList.add(map);
                   // }


                }
              /*  } else {
                    // no products found
                    // Launch Add New product Activity
                    //Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                           // NewProductActivity.class);
                    // Closing all previous activities
                    //i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                   // startActivity(i);
                }*/
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */

                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            listar_clientes.this, productsList,
                            R.layout.activity_list_item_clientes, new String[]{TAG_NOME, TAG_ABV},
                            new int[]{R.id.name, R.id.abv});
                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);



                }
            });

        }
    }
  }
```

and here the xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>



<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- Main ListView
         Always give id value as list(@android:id/list)
    -->



    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="#FFFFFF"
        android:dividerHeight="4px"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try to use current activity reference listar_clientes.this instead of getApplicationContext() when initialize Intent.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
// ListView Item Click Listener
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {

        switch(position){
             case 0: // list position
                 Intent intent = new Intent(listar_clientes.this, detalhes_cliente.class);
                 intent.putExtra(TAG_NOME, nome);
                 intent.putExtra(TAG_ABV, abv);
                 startActivity(intent);
             break;
        }

    }
});
```

**Edit**

**uncomment** the line: `list = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);`

Comment: you have to uncomment `list = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);`

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your ListView clickable..

Either in your Java file..

```
list.setClickable(true);
```

Or in xml listview..

```
 android:clickable="true"
```